Diffirent responses on very similar headers chrome extension
I'm writing chrome extension (last chrome version) on manifest v3 with js.
All queries and functions works correctly, but only one in my queries giving response status code 500. My query was sniffed from another query (so «another query» is original query on site, «my query» - means that i replacing another query with my query, because i need to push specific data in query), but it`s giving status code 200.
Both queries are haven`t context and prepares, so where can be difference?
I copied quieries with Chrome » Devtools » right click on query » Copy » Copy as fetch.
My query, which giving 500`s server response:
fetch('https://www.server.com/spt/betslips/betslip/toggleitem?betslipId=value here', {
  'headers': {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-language': 'fr,ru;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'betslipid': 'value here',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'priority': 'u=1, i',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24"',
    'sec-ch-ua-arch': '"x86"',
    'sec-ch-ua-bitness': '"64"',
    'sec-ch-ua-full-version': '"131.0.6778.86"',
    'sec-ch-ua-full-version-list': '"Google Chrome";v="131.0.6778.86", "Chromium";v="131.0.6778.86", "Not_A Brand";v="24.0.0.0"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-model': '""',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform-version': '"10.0.0"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'x-gw-application-name': 'NoviIE',
    'x-gw-betslipid': '1314396104817811456',
    'x-gw-channel': 'WebPC',
    'x-gw-client-timezone': 'Europe/Moscow',
    'x-gw-cms-key': '_IE',
    'x-gw-country-sysname': 'IE',
    'x-gw-currency-sysname': 'EUR',
    'x-gw-domain-key': '_IE',
    'x-gw-language-sysname': 'en-IE',
    'x-gw-odds-representation': 'Fractional',
    'x-gw-state-sysname': '',
    'Referer': 'https://www.server.com/live-betting/value here',
    'Referrer-Policy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',

  },
  'body': '{"betContextId":38188719,"betInstanceId":38188719,"marketInstanceId":1207665657,"price":2.5}',
  'method': 'POST',
});

Another query, is responsing OK 200:
fetch('https://www.server.com/spt/betslips/betslip/toggleitem?betslipId=value here', {
  'headers': {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-language': 'fr,ru;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'priority': 'u=1, i',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="131", "Chromium";v="131", "Not_A Brand";v="24"',
    'sec-ch-ua-arch': '"x86"',
    'sec-ch-ua-bitness': '"64"',
    'sec-ch-ua-full-version': '"131.0.6778.86"',
    'sec-ch-ua-full-version-list': '"Google Chrome";v="131.0.6778.86", "Chromium";v="131.0.6778.86", "Not_A Brand";v="24.0.0.0"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-model': '""',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform-version': '"10.0.0"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'x-gw-application-name': 'NoviIE',
    'x-gw-betslipid': 'value here',
    'x-gw-channel': 'WebPC',
    'x-gw-client-timezone': 'Europe/Moscow',
    'x-gw-cms-key': '_IE',
    'x-gw-country-sysname': 'IE',
    'x-gw-currency-sysname': 'EUR',
    'x-gw-domain-key': '_IE',
    'x-gw-language-sysname': 'en-IE',
    'x-gw-odds-representation': 'Fractional',
    'x-gw-state-sysname': '',
    'Referer': 'https://www.server.com/live-betting',
    'Referrer-Policy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',

  },
  'body': '{"betContextId":value here,"betInstanceId":value here,"marketInstanceId":value here,"price":1.2}',
  'method': 'POST',
});

I tried to make a similar request using Postman and other debug tools with the same headers and body and didn't get any errors, so I'm starting to think that it's a chrome bug and some headers it doesn't perceive.

The difference is that the first one has a separate betslipid header and the second one doesn't. This is not a standard header, so the difference in response is caused by the server, not the browser.

The Referer includes a placeholder at the end (e.g., /value here), which can potentially cause an error. However, I believe the issue might actually be related to the betslipid, as @woxxom mentioned.

Unfortunately it is verified that betslipid has no effect on the status code of the application. Referrer is not read by it at all as well(
